# Real 2D Analysis Question using Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

[image: Question]

My question is as above.

Currently I am stuck at the very start, part (i)! I can't come up with an appropriate $f$, even though I've been thinking about it for ages! If someone would be able to give me a hint as to what sort of properties $f$ would have, so that I can then try to determine what $f$ should be, then I'd be most appreciative! (If I still can't do it, then perhaps someone can just tell me what $f$ should be!)

Once I've got $f$, I would hope to be able to continue with the rest of the question (hope is the key word!), so I currently am only looking for help for the first part.

Thanks in advance! :)

PS - Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question - I've had a brief look, but quite hard to search for something so specific as this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try $f_1(t) = t + g(t)$ as a starting point. That certainly has the algebraic property you want...but does it take a disk into itself? (I think that this means that there's a disk $D$ with $f(D) \subset D$, rather than $f(D) = D$, which would be another reasonable interpretation). Probably not.

To prove the disk=-mapping property, you want to use the stuff you know. You know that $\| g(t) - t \| \le K$. Hmm. So you know something about $g(t) - t$, but that doesn't tell you anything about $g(t) + t$, which is what you're looking at.

Can you think of a better function to use than $f_1$, knowing that you want to reason about $g(t) - t$?

Comment: That was my starting point also, because it has the obvious required property. I then tried rewriting it as $f(x) = (g(x) - x)/2K + (1/2K + 1)x$, so that I can use the bound; this doesn't help though as then the natural bounding is $|f(x)| \le 1/2 + (1/2K + 1) \| x \||$. Are you able to give a bit more of a hint?

Comment: OK. You've clearly tried things and just bumped into a bunch of furniture and skinned your ankles when the thing you wanted was right in front of you. Having done that myself lots of times: try $f(t) = (1/K) (t - g(t))$. What's that do to points $t$ in the unit disk around the origin?

Comment: I also thought of that, but that doesn't possess the property that when $f(t) = t$ we have $g(t) = 0$; that's why I was trying to add on that extra bit of $t$, so as to get that property...

Comment: You're right..and you're on the right track, too. Sorry for my too-glib earlier comment.  Try $f(x) = \frac{x-g(x)}{K} + \frac{K-1}{K}x$. Now apply that to a point $x$ in the radius $K$ disk: $\|f(x)\| \le \|g(x)-x\|/K + ((K-1)/K) \|x\| \le 1 + ( (K-1)/K ) K = K$.

Comment: Ah yes, that's better: I was using $g(x) - x$ then adding on stuff; much better to use $x - g(x)$. The only slight issue now though is that $ \| f(x) \| \le K$, but we don't know that $K \le 1$; as such, we don't know that $f:D \rightarrow D$, but instead that $f:B(0,1) \rightarrow B(0,K)$.

Comment: Although Brouwer's theorem is for $B(0,1) \rightarrow B(0,1)$, I assume that it can actually work for $B(0,r) \rightarrow B(0,R)$ by rescaling? After all, there is no need for $f$ to be surjective...?

Comment: Look at my last comment: it shows that $B(0, K)$ is mapped by $f$ into $B(0, K)$. And yes, the Brouwer theorem works for disks of radius $K$ (the proof is identical). As for disks of different radii...I leave that to you to play with. As you observe, though, there's no requirement that $f$ be surjective.

Comment: Ah yes, $f$ maps $B(0,K)$ to itself, not $B(0,1)$ to $B(0,K)$. That sorts me out, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Urgh, if I read the question more carefully, I have just noticed that it says "$f$ takes **a** disc to itself" - I was trying to take "the" disc, ie the unit disc. Thanks again! :)